# Can the XML response change when running from weblogic?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, weblogic, soapui

I have a piece of code that, when running on my eclipse, produces the right result:

```
NodeList documentIdNodeList = soapResponse.getSOAPBody().getElementsByTagName("ns0:DocumentId");
NodeList documentNameNodeList = soapResponse.getSOAPBody().getElementsByTagName("ns0:DocumentName");
    printOrLog(documentNameNodeList.getLength());
```

when running it on my eclipse, it prints 1, which means that it sees the tag "DocumentName" once, which matches with what I see on soapUI (I'm seeing the response of a SOAP web service)

However when running it on weblogic, it logs 0, which means it doesn't find the tag DocumentName.

does running code from weblogic may alter the xml response?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible; but for sure it will comply with the WSDL.

Probably you will notice that the `DocumentName` is there (using SOAP UI) but maybe the namespace is not `ns0`.

Why not use JAX-WS to generate portable artifacts based on a WSDL file?

Comment: I'm new I am not really familiar with JAX-WS not sure what "portable artifacts " are either. Also the WSDL file is private from my company. It is not publicly accessible

Comment: It's quite simple. Let's assume that your are using NetBeans. You only need the wsdl (the same one that you are using in SOAPUI) and you can follow this  [instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wu02HxT6taU).  At the end you will use classes instead of processing the raw soap response and that will avoid the problems that you are facing now. I hope that this help you!